# Filtering out indented lines in JSON GitHub API with sed

Tags: json, linux, sed

I'm able get all the names filtered out using,

```
sed -n '/"name":/p' htop.json
```

but I want to filter out all the indented outputs. I'm looking for the repo titles from each GitHub. It's important I use something light like sed to make this small and portable.

Here is htop.json
https://pastebin.com/5xuH29yW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just filter from the beginning of the line with spaces/indentation characters then:

```
sed -n '/^      "name":/p' htop.json
```

and we can also specify the number of spaces as a number:

```
sed -n '/^[ ]\{6\}"name":/p' htop.json
```

Let's get repo names!

```
sed -n '/^      "name":/{s/[[:space:]]*"name":[[:space:]]*"\(.*\)",$/\1/;p}' htop.json
```

Comment: Neither examples are working, possibly my mistake. I'm including the full htop.json in the original post. Let me know if there is a better way than using pastebin.

Comment: Just wrong number of spaces. You posted identation of two spaces here, in that paste bin there are 6 spaces. I will edit the answer to have 6 spaces.

Comment: Very nice, Thank you very much! I'd up-vote, but I do not have the reputation yet. How did you learn such specific knowledge?

Comment: sed is a very common, well known and popular utility for parsing texts and using regex. I remember once I played [regex crosswords](https://regexcrossword.com/), such games are fun and will make your regex skill go through the roof in no time.